# I need to create json object in java. How will I do it?

Tags: java, android, json

```
[{
    id: 12345,      //Id given by android app
    name: Name,     
    status: {
        yes: [N1, n2, n3],  
        no: [n1, n2 ,n3]  
    }
}]
```

How will I write json object for this in java?

My Attempt:

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray();
try {
    object.put("id",12345);
    object.put("name",Name);
    jsonarray.put("yes");
    jsonarray.put("no");
} catch (JSONException js) {
    js.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think the problem is with jsonarray. I need to write again the jsonarray object. But I am not able to figure out how will I do it.

**Edit**

This question is not duplicate.

@ShaishavJogani I don't think this question is a duplicate of the question you provided a link to because this question is about generating JSON and this is about parsing JSON.

Comment: you mean you want to parse the above json?

Comment: What happens when you execute the code? Does it compile? Does it print an error message? What error message? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: BTW The code you posted has a syntactic error: you forgot a " after "no". Is this your actual code? If not, please copy-paste the actual code in.

Comment: @ShaishavJogani I don't think this question is a duplicate of the question you provided a link to because this question is about **generating** JSON and [this](//stackoverflow.com/questions/28302812/parse-json-to-string-android-studio) is about **parsing** JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `status` is also a `JSONObject`, `yes` and `no` are properties of this `JSONObject` of type `JSONArray` and the main object is in a `JSONArray`, so I would do it rather like this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("id", 12345);
object.put("name", "Name");
JSONObject status = new JSONObject();
object.put("status", status);
status.put("yes", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList("N1", "n2", "n3")));
status.put("no", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList("n1", "n2", "n3")));

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Collections.singletonList(object));
System.out.println(array);
```

**Output:**

```
[{"name":"Name","id":12345,"status":{"no":["n1","n2","n3"],"yes":["N1","n2","n3"]}}]
```

Comment: [`JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) has a `Collection` constructor, so you can shorten code, e.g. `status.put("yes", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList("N1", "n2", "n3")))`.

Comment: Please read it again. It is array or array. check at beginning..  @NicolasFilotto

Comment: @Andreas check my comment

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal fixed, check again

Comment: +1 for quick answer. If you don't mind can you tell me from where I can about JSON parsing @NicolasFilotto

Comment: where you can what?

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Assuming the missing word in your last comment is "read" or "learn", then search the web. You'll find lots of articles about JSON parsing there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope before array there will be a JSONObject or may be some name for array: Try below code if this array comes in a JSONObject:

```
try {    
               JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
               JSONArray jsonarray=object.getJSONArray();
                if(jsonarray.length()>0)
                {
                for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length();i++)
                {

                    object.put("id",12345);
                    object.put("name",Name);
                    jsonarray.put("yes");
                    jsonarray.put("no);
                }
              }
         }

         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

otherwise:

```
try {    

                   JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray("Name of Array");
                    if(jsonarray.length()>0)
                    {
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length();i++)
                    {

                        object.put("id",12345);
                        object.put("name",Name);
                        jsonarray.put("yes");
                        jsonarray.put("no);
                    }
                  }
             }

             catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
```